# vb.net time elapsed & time remaining according from progressbar value

Tags: .net, vb.net

i can calculate only percentage.. 
so can you gudie me about time elapsed and time remaining from progressbar value?

this is my code

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
        percent = percent + 1
        Label1.Text = percent
        ProgressBar1.Minimum = 0
        ProgressBar1.Maximum = 100

        If ProgressBar1.Value = 100 Then
            Timer1.Stop()
            MsgBox("done")
        Else
            ProgressBar1.Value = percent
            show_percent.Text = String.Format("{0:F0}%", ((ProgressBar1.Value / ProgressBar1.Maximum) * 100))
        End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would calculate the elapsed time using a `Stopwatch`. Calculating the expected total time and time remaining from that is simple arithmetic. Total time is elapsed time multiplied by maximum divided by the current and the remaining time is the total time less the elapsed time.